# Laravel media library not generating responsive images in production

Tags: laravel, laravel-medialibrary

In development, my code generates responsive images in a responsive_images directory. However, in production, it doesn't and does not throw any error as well. Only the original; image gets saved.

My Model.
I have striped some code to keep it simple

```
class Blog extends Model implements HasMedia
{
  use HasFactory;
  use InteractsWithMedia;


  // media library
  public function registerMediaCollections(): void
  {
    $this
      ->addMediaCollection('blog_main_photo')
      ->withResponsiveImages();
  }

}
```

My controller method.

```
public function store()
  {
    // after creating an article to create an article

    $article->addMedia(request()->file('image'))->toMediaCollection('blog_main_photo');
    return redirect()->back();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem however I found my mistake, check if your srcset is https in your production mode. You have to change this in your env file "APP_URL". On your development servers you probably have it set to just http.